# How can I place a <div> just above the centre using bootstrap behind a background image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place the picture of mine which is `<div class="shape">` on top of the background image which is `<div class="hero">` just above the center using bootstrap.

However, the background color and image both appear above my picture. I'm looking for the background image to go behind my picture and for the background color not to be seen at this moment in time.

Please don't delete the background color if you decide to help me as I want to do something with it at a later stage.

**Please open the snippet in full screen to see my issue.**

```css
<style>
      .body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: center;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      }
      .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
      }
      .nav.navbar-nav,
      .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      }
      .section {
      min-height: 100vh;
      }
      .one {
      background-color:#c00;
      }
      .two {
      background: #563D7C;
      }
      #sections .section {
      padding-top: ~50px;
      }
      .hero {
      background: url("http://mowebusa.nobletechindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/computer.jpg") center center no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position: relative;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100%;
      }
      .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 300px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      }
   </style>
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      <div id="sections">
         <div class="section one">
            <div class="shape"></div>
            <div class="hero"></div>
            <a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
         </div>
         <div class="section two"></div>
            <a href="#section one"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
      </div>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#sections').fullpage();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following the steps below:

1. add `position: absolute` to `.shape` to overlap the hero image.
2. add `z-index: 10` to get `.shape` on top of `.hero` image

Now, to center align a positioned element, keep in mind the following trick:

1. use `left: 50%` to put the positioned element 50% from the left.
2. add `margin-left: -150px`

The 1st step would have worked just fine if the element had width of `1px` (`.shape` will start after 50% from left) but since it has a width of `300px`, you will have to add a negative margin-left equal to half the width of the element (`300/2 = 150`).

Similarly, for vertical alignment you can use `top: 50%` and a negative `margin-top` equal to 1/2 of the `height`.

**Note:** There was issue on `padding-top: ~50px;`, remove the `~` as it is invalid token. Also, padding can't be in negative.

```css
.body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: #c00;
}

.two {
  background: #563D7C;
}

#sections .section {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.hero {
  background: url("http://mowebusa.nobletechindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/computer.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

.shape {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #4D5061;
  content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
  color: white;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 300px;

  /* add this */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div id="sections">
    <div class="section one">

      <div class="shape"></div>
      <div class="hero"></div>
      <a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="section two"></div>
    <a href="#section one"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sections').fullpage();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and the explanation is very much appreciated. Tick mark awarded.